# How to iterate loop inside array to fetch values from another array in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular8

#### In ts file, I have created following array :-

```
myimages: any=[
    {img_path:"assets/img/image1.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image2.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image3.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image4.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image5.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image6.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image7.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image8.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image9.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image10.jpg"}
];


galleryImages = [

    for (let i = 0; i < myimages.length; i++) {    
        small: 'myimages[i]',
        medium: 'myimages[i]',
        big: 'myimages[i]'
    }

];
```

I want image paths from myimages array into small, medium and big values in galleryImages array. I have tried above code, but for loop is throwing ts1137 error. Please someone help me as early as possible. This might be small issue but I am new to angular, so I am not getting correct solution for this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `map` function instead of a `for` loop.

If you haven't declared your variables with `const`, `let` or `var`, you need to do that too.

```
var myimages: any = [
  { img_path: "assets/img/image1.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image2.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image3.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image4.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image5.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image6.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image7.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image8.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image9.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image10.jpg" }
];


var galleryImages: any = myimages.map((x: any) => ({
  small: x,
  medium: x,
  big: x
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easier

```
myimages: any=[
    {img_path:"assets/img/image1.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image2.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image3.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image4.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image5.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image6.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image7.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image8.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image9.jpg"},
    {img_path:"assets/img/image10.jpg"}
];

const galleryImages: any = myimages.map((img: any) => ({
  small: img,
  medium: img,
  big: img
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

as a good practice, we feel that you should avoid using `any`. so the solution looks kind of like this

```js
interface Image {
   img_path: string;
};

const myimages: Image[] = [
  { img_path: "assets/img/image1.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image2.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image3.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image4.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image5.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image6.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image7.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image8.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image9.jpg" },
  { img_path: "assets/img/image10.jpg" }
];

const galleryImages = myimages.map(image => {
  return {
    small: image.img_path,
    medium: image.img_path,
    big: image.img_path
  };
});
```